# best_in_place and html_safe

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, overflow, best-in-place, html-safe

I'm using the [best_in_place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) in my rails app to allow for inline editing.  I'm running into issues with trying to render some text html safe.

Without specifying that the text should be made html_safe, this is what it looks like on the page:[image]

I looked at the best_in_place documentation and tried adding the following lines to render the text html safe:

```
  <div id="projectOverviewDescription">
      <p>

  <%= best_in_place @project.overview, :description, 
    :path => project_step_path(@project, @project.overview), 
    :type => :textarea, 
    :nil=> "Add a description of your project here!", 
    :display_with => lambda { |v| v.html_safe } %>

  </p>
</div>
```

But this ends up looking like the following:

[image]

It looks like the text ignores my css overflow rules and also, the best_in_place editing uses the nil placeholder ("add a description...") when there is a description already.  **What's the best way to produce html_safe text using best_in_place?**

Here's my css:

```
#projectOverviewDescription{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  height: 236px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  background: $titlegrey;
  opacity: 0.7;
  p{
    color: white;
    height: 236px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this gems that have more functionalities and may solve your problems

```
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'RedCloth'
```

find gem documentation here

[Ruby gems](http://rubygems.org/)

Comment: Try it out it will work because i have used them in my application and more information you can check on github.