# how to remove html tags while doing inline edit via 'Best in place' editing

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Am doing an inline edit using 'best in place' gem. Everything works fine but while edit with rich text document(when styles are applied) it is shows the same tags on the view page.

I tried with `:display_with => lambda { |v| v.html_safe }`
Almost works fine but edit area is not shows properly.Only a slight area will be shown because of the rich textbox usage.so any alternate instead of the above or any solution to existing.Thanks in advance

```
<td class= "index_view ipad_index_view">
    <%= best_in_place_if can?(:edit_goals),goal,:description,url: admin_goal_path(goal,:page => "inline"),:display_with => lambda { |v| v.html_safe } %>
</td>
```

Editing area is the entire area where the text with the alignment and styles given. Currently if normal edit done w/o using rich textfield everything works fine but while done with rich text box only at the beginning the edit area appears. 
The result is correct but the view is wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737192/best-in-place-and-html-safe     -This is the same isuue which am facing.This doesnot get any correct solution.Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

try using `raw` tag. something like `<%= raw @post.body %>` in your block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737192/best-in-place-and-html-safe     -am facing the same issue.a more clarified one.is this have any solution?!i will try this code also.thanks.

Comment: fine. how did it go? what did you do? have you fix it?

Comment: Sorry cant fix that.Except the view side everything works fine.the edit box for the text with rich text is showing error.A separate div tag(when styles applied via rich text editor(tinymce-rails gem))and only there best in place applied not on the edited word so appears separately.Cant expalin well by words.Could you please provide with your email id that i can disuss in detail.Thanks in advance